# Perform linear regression after box plot. Is that possible?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, boxplot

I am currently investigating a dataset with a visible linear relationship between the considered variable (Look at the red dots in the figure). However, the linear regression results are not good due to the data's extreme variance (look at the y-axis). For the sake of clarity, these values are correct. They are not outliers.

I then divided the dataset into groups, considering the variable on the x-axis, and I calculated each group's average value (using a boxplot method). Finally, I applied a linear regression on the average value I got from the boxplots, obtaining good results.

The question is: is that procedure possible, or could it be considered like “cheating”?

Moreover, is it possible to quantify or explain how this is different from doing the regression directly on the scatter plot, and not the binned averages?

[image]

Comment: +1 It's not cheating--but you can do much better than that.  For examples, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=+wandering+schematic+plot.

Comment: What are these data? What do you want from them? Almost certainly, we can point you to better methods, if we know more about your situation & your goals.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the datas show  extreme value for all X values that are all above the global trend : it is clearly not gaussien... Try a glm with gamma distribution.

(We can see on the plot that the trend is very weak though : The behaviour does not change much for differrent values of X, so the regression's coefficient for the variable X should be close to zero. I do not think a regression is very pertinent in that case. So I would also try to model Y with a gamma distribution (without X involved) and compare the two options with the AIC criterion.)